# UITableView Reordering Of Cells-Reorder/Edit Mode Not Displaying (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` inside a `UIViewController`. I am trying to make it so when the user click the  `BarButtonItem` in the `NavigationBar`, that the tableview goes into editing mode, and thus the user can drag and reorder the cells.

However, what happens is that I simply press the editing button, and nothing happens.

This is what I have tried:

For the array declaration:

```
 var tester = ["1", "2", "3"]
```

For the button declaration:

```
   @IBAction func editButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
          self.editing = !self.editing
    }
```

For the various tableview functions:

```
   func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return tester.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("editCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! EditTableViewCell
        cell.nameHolder?.text = tester[indexPath.row]



        // Configure the cell...

        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var itemToMove = tester[fromIndexPath.row]
        tester.removeAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
        tester.insert(itemToMove, atIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    }




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
        return true
    }
```

What could be causing this bug?

Comment: Can you please try to change the editing flag on the tableView and not on on self ? self.tableView.editing = !self.tableView.editing

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.1**

In → `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {`

Add this line to configure the cell:

```
cell.isEditing = self.tableView(tableView, canMoveRowAt: indexPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran Hassid has the most correct answer to this in his comment.
This will solve the problem:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBAction func editButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    tableView.setEditing(!tableView.isEditing, animated: true)
}
```